# Atom Payment Gateway integration In Flutter Application

Tags: android, flutter, payment, gateway

I am trying to implement `atom` payment gateway in my Flutter app (Android), but unfortunately atom doesn't provide an `SDK` for `Flutter`. How can I implement it in `Flutter`. Is it possible to achieve using method channelling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use method channels to call platform-specific methods from flutter.

I've had a similar situation when I had to use [paytabs](https://www.paytabs.com/) SDK for iOS and Android. 
I've used method channels to channel the parameters to the sdks on the platforms. 
It's working very well actually.

I don't know about ATOM but you can take a look at the SDK I made for flutter [here](https://github.com/MajedDH/flutter_paytabs_sdk).  It's just a working example to start from.

Comment: I have used method channel on android it worked. but it was difficult on ios. so I implemented it in webview. thanks anyway.